# Not able to type in VS Code Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the terminal it would usually say bash4.2$ then I could type in commands after that. Now, it doesn't say bash4.2, just a box and I can't type anything. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but that didn't fix the issue. Here is a screenshot of the [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQu3X.png). How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Here are my user settings:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\bash.exe",
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "Google",
    "C_Cpp.default.intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
    ],
    "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++11"
}
```

Comment: how did you run your script? By clicking on the arrow in the upper right?

Comment: No, I need to type to run my script by typing ./ then the filename. I can't type anything so I'm not able to run anything.

Comment: You didn't provide platform you are using or terminal settings, I can't help more but to just link you [documentation on terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).

Comment: I could tell you the settings and platform, but I'm not sure how to find these?